# How to query for entity commited yesterday by DateTimeProperty()

Tags: python, google-app-engine, filter, jinja2

I have a calendar model that records the number of contributions users make per day:

```
class CalModel(db.Model):
    user = db.ReferenceProperty(UserModel, collection_name = "calendar")
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
    contrib = db.IntegerProperty(required = True)
```

I want to query for the CalModel entity whose date attribute is yesterday. How do I specify a datetime object that whose day is yesterday? (The strftime format is the default)

Something that goes like:

```
cal = CalModel.all().filter("date", DATETIMEOBJECT).get()
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
yesterday = datetime.today() - timedelta(1)
query = CalModel.all().ancestor(calendar_key()).filter("user", user).filter("date", yesterday).get()
```